# Limit points of subsequences of $(a_n)$ are equal to limit points of A?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence and consider subsequences $(a_{{p_k}_n})$ $k=1,2,3,......$, that means we consider infinitely many subsequences of $a_n$. Suppose these subsequences are pairwise disjoint and form the sequences $(n)$. If $S, S_{p_1}, S_{p_2}, ... $ are set of limit points of $(a_n), (a_{{p_k}_n}) $, we want to prove that

$$ S = \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} S_{p_k} $$

And use this to prove that if every subsequences $(a_{{p_k}_n}) $ converges to $L$, then $a_n \to L$.

### Attempt:

If $x \in \bigcup S_{p_k}$, then $x \in S_{p_k}$ for some $k$ so there exists a subsequence of the subsequence $(a_{p_{k_n}})$ of $(a_n)$ that converges to $x$ by definition of limit point. But, this subsequence of the subsequence is itself a subsequence of $(a_n)$. In other words, we have found a subsequence of $(a_n)$ that converges to $x$: $x \in S$. We have $ \boxed{ \bigcup_{k \geq 1} S_{p_k} \subset S }$

It is the other direction that it hard: We can instead prove that  $( \bigcup S_{p_k} )^c \subset S^c \iff \bigcap S^c_{p_k} \subset S^c$. So if $x \in \bigcap S^c_{p_k} $ then $x$ is in every $S_{p_k}^c $.

Now, $x \notin S_{p_k}$ means that $x$ is not a limit point of $S_{p_k}$. How can we negate the statement of not being a limit point: Is it that there is no subsequnece that converges to $x$? or is it that every subsequence not converges to $x$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement to be proved is false. Let $\mathbb{P}$ the set of primes and WLOG suppose that $L=0$, then for every $p\in \mathbb{P}$ set a subsequence defined by $a_{p^k}:=1/k$ for $k\in \mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$, and let any other $a_m:=0$ if $m\neq p^k$ for some prime $p$ and some $k\in \mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$.

Then by construction the subsequences $(a_{p^k})_{k\in \mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}}$ are all mutually disjoint for distinct $p\in \mathbb{P}$ and converges to zero, however each subsequence $(a_{p^k})_{p\in \mathbb{P}}$ is constantly $1/k$, so $1/k$ is a limit point of $(a_n)$ for each $k\in \mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: Sorry to say this, but the main result may be false. It only works for finitely many: Consider:
$$ a_n = \begin{cases} 0 & n = 2^k, k=1,2,3,.. \\ 1 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

Then, every subsequence $(a_{2k-1}), (a_{2(2k-1)}),... (a_{2^m (2k - 1)} ) $ converge to 1. a_n diverges tho

Comment: another one: $(a_{2^k}), (a_{2^{2k}}),... (a_{2^{mk}} )$ they all converge to $0$

Comment: sorry, I had misunderstood your question, I edited my answer

Comment: So, in your example, $S = \{  0,1,1/2,.... \}$ but $S_{p_{k}} = 0 $ $\forall k$

Comment: @Theoneandonly yes, that is. To complete the picture we need to add the subsequence that completes the indices such that they are a partition of ${\mathbb N}$. For this other subsequence I had set every element to zero